# ¿Cómo ordenar una matriz en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo esta matriz:

```
     hr age
[1,] 62  63
[2,] 69  63
[3,] 69  40
[4,] 68  40
[5,] 67  40
[6,] 75  40
[7,] 76  47
```

Y necesito ordenarla por edad y luego por hr. Es decir, los más jóvenes primero y, si hay coincidencia de edad, que el orden lo determine hr (menor hr, más arriba). Sé que puedo hacerlo con `sort`, pero cuando aplico esta función, solo se me ordena la columna de age y no se altera de la hr. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto puedes usar [`order()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html):

```
m <- matrix(c(62,69,69,68,67,75,76,63,63,40,40,40,40,47), ncol=2)
colnames(m) <- c("hr", "age")

m[order(m[,"age"], m[,"hr"]), ]

     hr age
[1,] 67  40
[2,] 68  40
[3,] 69  40
[4,] 75  40
[5,] 76  47
[6,] 62  63
[7,] 69  63
```

En este caso, con `order(m[,"age"], m[,"hr"])` conseguimos generar un vector de orden, en primer lugar por la columna `age` y luego,por `hr`, en este caso `[1] 5 4 3 6 7 1 2` luego simplemente lo aplicamos a la matriz para obtener una nueva matriz ordenada en la dimensión de las filas, es decir `m[<orden>,]`

Comment: En el "m[order(m[,"age"], m[,"hr"]), ]", es necesario dejar la coma final para que te salga la matriz. ¿Por qué? A parte de eso, muchas gracias, estaba atascada en esta tontería.

Comment: Por que lo que buscamos es ordenar las filas, de ahí la última coma, para que el order se aplique sobre la dimensión de filas.